# Creating a matrix from vector replication, python

Tags: python, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have a vector `V` of size `n`. I would like to create a matrix of size `n*n`, so that each value in the matrix will be `M(i,j) = V(i)*V(j)`.

Many loops will solve it, but I need it to be rather fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called the outer product

```
import numpy as np

v = np.random.randint(0, 10, 3)
print v

M = np.outer(v,v)
print M
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using numpy.  However, this is a pure python solution using list comprehension:

```
v = [5, 1, 9]
>>> [[row * col for row in v] for col in v]
[[25, 5, 45], [5, 1, 9], [45, 9, 81]]
```